# Base of Subspace with vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Let E be the vector subspace of $R^3$ generated by it vectors $v1 = (1,2,0)$ and $v2 = (-1,0,2)$

How can find a basis of E between the following vectors?
$$w1=(-2,-12,8), w2=(-12,-2,-8), w3=(-2,-3,1), w4=(1,-1,-3), w5=(6,3,-9), w6=(0,1,1)$$

I know that I have to demonstrate some effort solving the exercise first. I'm really lost with vectors and subspaces.

I tried $$a(1,2,0) + b(-1,0,2) = w1=(-2,-12,8)$$
$a = -6$

$b = 4$

$a-b=-2$ But this is not satisfied, thus $w1$ is not a basis.

I wonder if I'm in the right path, which are the conditions with the right basis?

I have found that with $w3,w4,w6$ the three above equations are satisfied. Now what can I do with this?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you need to do with the $w_k$? Some of them lie in $E$ some don't. I would guess that you need to see which ones lie in $E$ and use these to generate the basis of $E$?

Comment: I need to find a base between the vectors $wk$
$$w3,w4,w6$$ don't lie. So, what I need to do with these vectors?

Comment: None of the $w_i$ is a multiple of another. So if you can find two of them in the space generated by $v_1$ and $v_2$, you will be finished. This can be attempted like you started. The fact that one of the last two coordinates of the $v_i$ is $0$ makes the job easier.

Comment: Since the dimension of $E$ is two, any basis has two elements. As  André suggested, start from the end :-).

Comment: @copper.hat I don't understand you. Could you be more explicit please?

Comment: Well, from  André: None of the $w_k$ is a multiple of each other (this saves some time). So, if you can find two different $w_k$ that lie in $E$, you are finished. I suggested starting from the end. That is, can you write $(1,1,0)$ and $(6,3,-9)$ as multiples of the basis of $E$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the $w_i$ is a multiple of another. So if you can find two of them in the space generated by $v_1$ and $v_2$, you will be finished. This can be attempted like you started. The fact that one of the last two coordinates of the $v_i$ is $0$ makes the job easier.

We deal first with $w_1$. If $w_1=av_1+bv_2$, then from the last two coordinates we see that we must have $a=-6$ and $b=4$. Then the first coordinate of $av_1+bv_2$ would be $-10$. But this is not the first coordinate of $w_1$, so $w_1$ is eliminated.

Let's look at $w_6$. Looking at the last two coordinates, if this is to be $av_1+bv_2$ we need $a=1/2$ and $b=1/2$. That works, for it produces the right first coordinate of $w_6$. 
Since $w_6=(1/2)v_1+ (1/2)v_2$, it is in the space spanned by $v_1$ and $v_2$.

Thus $w_1$ is no good, and $w_6$ is good. Four left to examine!

Comment: I examined all and $w3,w4,w6$ are correct.
My question is, need I to do something with these correct $wk$?

Comment: Check your calculations. I agree about $w_4$, but not about $w_3$.  I think you will end up concluding that the only two pair that give a basis are $w_4$ and $w_6$.

Comment: for $w3$
$a=-3/2$, $b=1/2$, $a-b=2$

Comment: I am having trouble as usual with minus signs. For $w_3$ we need $a=-3/2$, $b=-1/2$, That makes the first coordinate $-1$.  But it is supposed to be $-2$. So $w_3$ is bad, it is not in $E$.  I think $w_5$ is also in $E$.

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo $w3=(-2,-3,1)$
I fixed it above too. Your $b=1/2$ now

Comment: Then $w_3$ is OK. We may have our choice, any two of the "good" vectors you find.

Comment: Now, we have the three vectors, $w3,w4,w6$  What I need to do?

Comment: Any **two** of them will give a basis of $E$. So you have $3$ choices of answer. U pick! Maybe the problem setter slipped, for grading it is more convenient if there is a single answer.

Comment: Let's say I choose $w3$ and $w6$, this is all?
My answer could be: "The basis of E are $w3$ and $w6$" or I need to do something else before I give the answer?

Comment: I get $w_3, w_4, w_5, w_6 \in E$. So pick any two. (Note that the only way two non-zero vectors can fail to span a space of dimension two is if they lie on the same line.)

Comment: You have to (i) express your two chosen people as a linear combination of $v_1$ and $v_2$; (ii) observe they are linearly independent; (ii) say that $E$ has dimension $2$, and you have found two linearly independent vectors in it, so you have found a basis. (The grader may be satisfied with less, but I would not be.)

Comment: @André Nicolas, thanks a lot professor :), I won't disappoint you!!

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer but this is how you can solve the problem.

The approach that I would do is as follows. We can write a matrix using the vectors that are elements of our subspace as coloumn vectors of the matrix. From what you wrote I believe this is $w_3, w_4, w_6$. So

\begin{bmatrix}
-2 & -1 & 0 \\
-3 & -1 & 1 \\
-1 & -3 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}

Now reduce to row echelon form and every column that has a pivot indicates the original column vector that forms a basis for our subspace, $E$.